# How compilation is going on below two programs?

Tags: java

First program:

```
  class first{
    first(){
      System.out.println("This is no-org constructor");
    }
  }

  class second extends first{
    second(){
      super();
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
      second f=new second();
    }
  }
```

**output:** This is no-org constructor

second program:

```
class first{
  first(){
    System.out.println("This is no-org constructor");
  }
}

class second extends first{  
  /*second(){super();} This part is deleted from first program*/
  public static void main(String a[]){
    second f=new second();
  }
}
```

**output:** This is no-org constructor

The output of the both programs is same.  Then, how can first constructor invoked and produces output.

Comment: Please clarify what it is exactly that is confusing you.

Comment: and please format your code.

Comment: Instead of of using same System.out.println("This is no-org constructor"); content in the both classes change the println statements as
       System.out.println("This is first constructor");
       System.out.println("This is second constructor");

Comment: Have a look at my edits in the question.

Comment: Both the above programs are same and I've just deleted                     second{ super();} from the second one. Then how can first constructor invoked and produces the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in your 2nd Program you haven't created any construtor So a Default Constructor is provided to your Class `Second` by Java Compiler

```
class second extends first
{  
 second(){ // this constructor provided by Compiler
 super();// ByDefault this statement exist in Any Constructor if not explicitly mentioned
 }
public static void main(String a[])
{
second f=new second();
}
}
```

and

`super()` is calling your parent class `No-arg-Constructor` .

That is why your Parent Class Constructor is called .

Answer (score 1):

In Java, if you don't provide a constructor, it creates one for you.  See [JLS 8.8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)

> If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no arguments.

This constructor must still initialise any parent class and it will call the default/empty argument constructor of it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same because if you do not explicitly call a `super` constructor in your class and the class you are extending has a no-argument constructor, an implicit `super()` is inserted into the beginning of your constructor. It is why you don't have a `super` is EVERY constructor you ever write despite every class directly or indirectly extending `Object`.